# Need Help? In one shopping cart price rule can we create two discounts 10% and 5% for 2 categories or more?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

We sell copier parts, for one manufacturer Konica Minolta we want to give 10% off and for other manufacturer Ricoh we want to give 5% off. So in shopping cart if customer buys products from both manufacturers, both discounts which are different 10% and 5%should be applied in same checkout when he applies the coupon code. So is it possible to create one shopping cart price rule for 2 categories are more with different percentages of discounts ? Hope I explained well if any confusion you can ask. I need help on urgent basis.We have magento 1.9 on our website

Answer (score 0):

Use observer , add to cart after . 
Then check id of users and  give disscount , or regural price.
If you want , you can write to me , i have custom rule module .

---

ok, another method. Create new 2 groups of users, first group - Konica Minolta  , second group - Ricoh .
Create price rule for customer group Konica Minolta , your discount amount and for Ricoh.  That is all.!

Comment: Alright. Well this option is not applicable in our case.Thanks

Comment: ok, another method.

Answer (score 0):

Magento allows multiple rules to be applied.

In your case create two Shopping Cart Price Rule, one for 10% off and 5% off. 
Apply these settings to both:

- Set Rule Information > **Coupon = No Coupon**
- Set Actions > **Stop Further Rules Processing = No**

Then add your unique conditions to each rule in:

- Actions > **Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions**

Comment: We want to make a coupon code for both percentages, that will applied at checkout page as we have option to apply discount code to get off. So if we will select no coupon then how will I get a coupon code ? And If there are 2 rules ( 2 coupon codes ) then if customer buys from both manufacturers he will be unable to get discount. Actually this discount is limited with coupon code only a person who will apply coupon code at checkout will get off

Comment: We don't want to give discount for everyone coming on website. These discounts are for those customers only who apply coupon code at checkout and we have to give different discount percentages for both manufacturer products. So if a customer add products from both manufactures (categories) , then after applying coupon code at checkout two different discounts should be applied 10% on one category products and 5% off for other categories. Hope you understand my point.

Comment: If you chose to use a coupon, you can only apply one coupon at a time.

Comment: So you mean we cant give 2 percentages discounts 10% and 5% through one coupon code ? right ?

Comment: Yes, it is not supported out-of-the-box.